# Issues Navigating Top Three Google Results with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, automation, browser-automation

Hi StackOverflow community,

I'm having an issue with a Selenium script I wrote to automate Google searches and navigate through the first three web pages of the search results. Below, I present a summary of what my code is supposed to do:

Using Selenium, I open Chrome and navigate to Google.
I input a query into the search box ("Dónde ir el día de muertos") and submit the search.
Once the search results have loaded, I attempt to click on the links of the first three organically positioned web pages.
After visiting a page, I wait for a few seconds and then go back to the Google results page to click on the next link.
To handle possible exceptions, I've added a retry mechanism. If for some reason I can't access a link, I refresh the page and try again. If after three attempts I still can't access the link, I skip it and move on to the next.

The problem I face is that in some cases, the code can't find the desired link, even after several attempts, and it throws exceptions like TimeoutException or NoSuchElementException. I'm pretty sure the links are present, but for some reason, my code can't always interact with them.

Could someone take a look and provide some guidance on what might be going wrong or how I can improve my code to make it more reliable?

Here's the snippet of the code I'm using. Thank you in advance for any assistance!

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException, NoSuchWindowException

import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + r"C:\Users\Mauricio Tellez\Downloads\chromedriver-win32\chromedriver-win32"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

link = "https://www.google.com.mx/?hl=es"
browser.get(link)

search_box = browser.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
search_box.send_keys('Donde ir el dia de muertos')
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

for i in range(3):
    retries = 3
    while retries:
        try:
            result = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"h3.LC20lb.MBeuO.DKV0Md:nth-of-type({i+1})"))) #HTML tag of each website
            result.click()
            browser.implicitly_wait(5)
            browser.back()
            break
        except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException):
            retries -= 1
            if not retries:
                print(f"Couldn't access link {i+1}. Skipping...")
                break
            browser.refresh()

browser.quit()
```